# How to prevent usage of certain classes in new code in Maven project?

Tags: java, maven, legacy-code, dependency-exclusion

There is a class `abc.something.MyComponent` that is used by some legacy code, but we want to avoid using it in newly created code.

I'm thinking about something like `maven-enforcer-plugin` with additional option to create a list of "allowed violations", because it is not possible to remove all usages instantly.

What is appropriate approach to add rules of a certain class usage in Java project?

Comment: declare them deprecated, provide an alternative and remove it in a future version. I wouldn't, however, go and look for a way beyond that. Seems a bit overkill. Just let the developer know that using it is on his own responsibility

Comment: Activate the appropriate warnings via java compiler (-Xlint:all, -Xlint:-processing) and you will see all deprecations. Mark the code as deprecated as already suggested ... cleanest way...

Comment: What I missed that if you mark things deprecated your IDE will give already hints... during the time you are writing the code..other solution might be an add-on but from point of view too late...

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use Checkstyle's [IllegalType](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/checks/coding/illegaltype.html#IllegalType) check. Checkstyle can easily be integrated in a Maven build using the [Maven Checkstyle plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/). It can be configured to simply create a report or to run its checks during the normal build and [even fail the build](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/usage.html#checking-for-violations-as-part-of-the-build) if any violation is found.

Here's how the general configuration would look like:

```
<module name="IllegalType">
  <property name="illegalClassNames" value="abc.something.MyComponent"/>
</module>
```

If you want to suppress violations about specific uses in legacy code, you could further configure "suppressions", as shown [here](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/filters/suppressionfilter.html#Examples). You can use file patterns and also restrict the suppressions to specific checks.

Comment: First and last links are broken.